# JSON API response for a collection POST that couldn't be performed

Tags: json-api

I am building an API where one can issue a `POST` to `/users/1/suggestions/make` in order to get a new suggestion. There are two cases:

- the server can create a suggestion based on `POST`ed params, in which case a `200` status code is returned together with the created suggestion;
- the server cannot create a suggestion based on `POST`ed params, in which case I am not sure what status code to return (`200`, since the request succeeded but nothing could be suggested, `404` because a suggestion could not be computed, or something else) and what content (`nil`, an empty response, something else).

Comment: In my opinion a `200` status should be returned, as it shows that the request was successful, and return a JSON that displays a message, such as `no suggestions made for the given input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `POST` is unsuccessful due to the parameters not passing validation, it is appropriate to return `HTTP 400 Bad Request`. The response body should consist of a list of the errors that caused the rejection.

This way it is clear to the API caller that no data has been modified.

Comment: This sounds logic, but I actually don't have validation errors involved. I send some params and based on them it's the server's job to compute a suggestion. This means that a query is run in the database and if it returns something, a `Suggestion` object is created. Otherwise, it isn't. Therefore you can't issue a bad request; all requests are valid, it's just what the server is able to deliver.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misinterpreted your intent. In that case, a `200` with an empty body or `{ "suggestion": null }` would be fine.

Comment: Or maybe a `204` that states that the request succeeded but there is no content?

Comment: Yes, I think the choice between an empty `200` and a `204` comes down to personal preference.